# html table to CSV, formatting problem in csv

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, csv, export-to-csv

I am stuck with idea on creating proper CSV from an html table. I am using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to read the html from string and create a HTMLDocument. Then I am using XPATH to loop through rows and columns.

The problem is that I am unable to determine the correct row and cell(x,y) for a particular cell.

Example HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                100
            </td>
            <td>
                200
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                300
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                400
            </td>
            <td>
                600
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                400
            </td>
            <td>
                500
            </td>
            <td>
                600
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image of Table](http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/2284/tablezw.jpg)

When I open it in excel and save as CSV, I do get the desired output, which is:

```
100,200,300,
,400,,600
400,500,600,
```

Can someone help me create the same output in .Net respecting the rowpan and colspan?

Thanks!
Dex

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know which row and column are you on. All you need to do is add a "," for each new column you found and a breakline every time you reach the end of a row.

If you navigate through the document considering it an xml document all you have to do is go through all TR nodes adding a breakline when you reach the end of the child nodes list. And iterate through all TD nodes on each TR node adding a "," when necessary.